# Cambiar bandera de idioma segun el idioma escogido

Tags: php, html

Tengo este codigo en el que el usuario elige una bandera y cambia de idioma el problema es que cuando elige un idioma siempre muestra el mismo en la minibanderita porque nose como cambiarlo, alguien sabría hacer que mostrara la banderita del idioma elegido en la banderita del desplegable? En resumen quiero que cambie la imagen de la banderita segun sea la adecuada.

```html
<span class="dropdown language">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true"><img src="/img/es.png" alt="español" class="idioma">
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>
      <a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], '?lang=es' ?>">
      <img src="/img/es.png" alt="español" class="idioma"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], '?lang=en' ?>">
      <img src="/img/uk.png" alt="english" class="idioma"></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</span>
```

No he adjuntado css pero si fuera el caso que va automatico pondria el nombre del idioma y se vería la banderita adecuada en el desplegable. gracias

Imagino que sería algo similar a esto

```html
    
    <span class="dropdown language">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    <?php 
    if ('?lang=es'){
      print('<img src="/img/es.png" alt="español" class="idioma">');
    }
    else{
      print('<img src="/img/uk.png" alt="english" class="idioma">');
    }
    ?>
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>
      <a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], '?lang=es' ?>">
      <img src="/img/es.png" alt="español" class="idioma"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], '?lang=en' ?>">
      <img src="/img/uk.png" alt="english" class="idioma"></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Más bien, en lugar de esto:

```
    <?php 
    if ('?lang=es'){
      print('<img src="/img/es.png" alt="español" class="idioma">');
    }
    else{
      print('<img src="/img/uk.png" alt="english" class="idioma">');
    }
    ?>
```

debería ser esto:

```
<?php 
$lang = isset($_GET['lang']) ? $_GET['lang'] : 'es';  // asignamos el 'es' por defecto si no hay parámetro en la url
// $lang = $_GET['lang'] ?? 'es';  // (para PHP versión 7 o superior) asignamos el 'es' por defecto si 
if ($lang == 'es'){
    print('<img src="/img/es.png" alt="español" class="idioma">');
} else {
    print('<img src="/img/uk.png" alt="english" class="idioma">');
}
?>
```

Pero si vas a seguir agregando más idiomas en el futuro lo podrías hacer así:

```
<?php
$lang = isset($_GET['lang']) ? $_GET['lang'] : 'es';  //  (para PHP versión inferior a la 7) asignamos el 
// $lang = $_GET['lang'] ?? 'es';  //  (para PHP versión 7 o superior) asignamos el 'es' por defecto si no hay idioma establecido en la url
switch($lang) {
  case 'es':
      $nombre_idioma = "español";
      break;
  case 'uk':
      $nombre_idioma = "english";
      break;
  default:
      $lang = 'es';  //cambiamos el $lang porque el recibido no existe y lo forzamos a 'es'
      $nombre_idioma = "español";
      break;
}
print('<img src="/img/'.$lang.'.png" alt="'.$nombre_idioma.'" class="idioma">');
?>
```

y de este modo podrás ir agregando más idiomas en los **case** facilmente.

Comment: Me causa un error en la web stderr: PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset, lo he agregado dentro del button donde estaba la imagen del español

Comment: que versión de PHP usas?  el operador `??` existe a partir de la versión 7, sinó tendré que cambiar la respuesta

Comment: @Sara11 He actualizado mi respuesta, a ver si ahora te funciona mejor (entiendo que el problema solo puede ser de la versión de PHP, a menos que me digas que aún no te funciona)

Comment: diria que es la version 7.4 de php, sigue sin funcionar

Comment: @Sara11 ¿y ese error es debido al código de la respuesta? Te dice la línea y coincide con la respuesta?

Answer (score 1):

Otra forma de hacerlo sería definiendo las asociaciones en un array. Para mi gusto es más portable, más fácil de mantener, más flexible y más limpio.

```
$allLangs=array("es"=>"español", "uk"=>"english", "en"=>"english", "fr"=>"french");

$langKey=!empty($_GET['lang']) ? $_GET['lang'] : 'es'; 
/*
   En PHP 7+ puedes usas fusión de null
   $langKey=$_GET['lang'] ?? 'es'; 
*/
   

$langName=$allLangs[$langKey];

# Para prueba solamente
echo $langName;
```

La ventaja aquí es que si quieres agregar más casos, sólo creas una nueva entrada en `$allLangs`.

Además, puedes usar esa estructura para crear tu `src` con algo como esto:

```
printf('<img src="/img/%s.png" alt="%s" class="idioma">',$langKey, $langName);
```

De modo que esto, ya no es necesario tampoco, y el código funcionará con dos idiomas o con cien idiomas:

```
if ('?lang=es'){
  print('<img src="/img/es.png" alt="español" class="idioma">');
}
else{
  print('<img src="/img/uk.png" alt="english" class="idioma">');
}
```